# CakePHP check referer

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following code:

```
function success()
    {
        if(!$this->referer(array('controller'=>'contact','action'=>'index')))
        {
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'contact','action'=>'index'));
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to check if the user has accessed the success page from the index action and if not then send them back to the index method so they can't view the success page if they haven't previously submitted some data on the index action.

It doesn't work however as the user can still visit the success page even if they haven't visited the index page first...

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
function success()
{
    if($this->referer() != Router::url(array('controller'=>'contact','action'=>'index')))
    {
        $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'contact','action'=>'index'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try to add ***true*** on the end of Router::url, function to get full url:

```
if($this->referer() != Router::url(array('controller'=>'contact','action'=>'index'),true))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that won't work like that. You are now just setting default referer with that code. Try something like:

```
if($this->referer() != Router::url(array('controller'=>'contact','action'=>'index')))
```

Edit: corrected the code

Comment: Gives the following error (line 41 is the line you have provided)

`Notice (8): Undefined property: ContactController::$Html [APP/controllers/contact_controller.php, line 41]
Fatal error: Call to a member function url() on a non-object in /nfs/c03/h01/mnt/52704/domains/driz.co.uk/html/app/controllers/contact_controller.php on line 41`

Comment: Do you have html-helper in use? `var $helpers = array('Html');`

Comment: what are you guys doing? this is a helper and should not be used in the controller this way.. simply use Router::url()!

Comment: Thanks Mark to pointing that out. How stupid I am to think that works in controller? :)